# Analyzing Set of all Perfect squares

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have been reading Velleman's `How to Prove` book and the following statement in the book confuses me:

For example, suppose we wanted to define S to be the set of all perfect squares. Perhaps the easiest way to describe this set is to say that it consists of all numbers of the form $n^2$, where n is a natural number. This is written $S = \{n^2 \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$. Note that we could also define this set by writing $S = \{ x \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N}(x=n^2)\}$

The last logical form confuses me. Shouldn't it be like this:

$S = \{ x \mid \forall n \in \mathbb{N}(x=n^2)\}$

Comment: The second describes the empty set. Since $1^2 \neq 2^2$, there is no $x$ that simultaneously equals all squares of natural numbers.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I get that now. Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part on the left of the "$\mid$" is a "prototype" for an element of the set.  The part on the right describes what must hold for such a prototype to actually be in the set.  The first definition means you can find some $n$ so that your prototype $x$ is equal to $n^2$.  So, if e.g. $x$ is $36$, you can find $n=6$, so $x$ is in the set.  Your second definition would mean that $x$ could only be in the set if it were simultaneously equal to *all* $n^2$ for all $n$ and as there is no such $x$ your set would be empty.

Comment: What if `x` is `7` ?

Comment: If $x=7$ then there is no $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n^2=x$, i.e. the sentence $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (x=n^2)$ is false and thus $x\notin S$.